# Adding items to a new array with index

Tags: arrays, ruby

Trying to make a method `skip_animals` that takes an `animals` array and a `skip` integer and returns an array of all elements except first `skip` number of items.

input: `skip_animals(['leopard', 'bear', 'fox', 'wolf'], 2)`

expected output: `["2:fox", "3:wolf"]`

```
   def skip_animals(animals, skip)
        arr = Array.new
        animals.each_with_index{|animal, index| arr.push("#{animal}:#{index}") }
        puts arr.drop(skip)
    end
```

This instead `puts` each output on a separate line and doesn't add them to the array `arr`.  I thought the `arr.push` would add them correctly.  What do I have to do to get the elements added to the array?

I want to use these methods, not `map` or something more advanced.  I need to tinker with this `each_with_index` line, not overhaul it.

(This is a challenge on Hackerrank, so it uses STDIN and STDOUT)

EDIT

Here is my updated code with `p` instead of `puts`.  It's giving me a weird output of two different arrays, not sure why.

```
def skip_animals(animals, skip)
    arr = Array.new
    animals.each_with_index{|animal, index| arr.push("#{index}:#{animal}") }
    p arr.drop(skip)
end
```

This gives me two lines of output:

```
["3:panda", "4:tiger", "5:deer"]
["0:leopard", "1:bear", "2:fox", "3:wolf", "4:dog", "5:cat"]
```

I'm assuming the top is the correct array, but I don't get why the second is printing also, or why it has a different set of animals.

Comment: Why can't you use `map`? I hope you are not going to say this is homework and you are trying to let someone else do the homework for you.

Comment: @sawa lol its an online problem on a learn to code site, not homework.  So the goal is to learn why this isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`p`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-p) instead of [`puts`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/IO.html#method-i-puts).

```
irb(main):001:0> puts ['1', '2']
1
2
=> nil
irb(main):002:0> p ['1', '2']
["1", "2"]
```

According to [the documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core/IO.html#method-i-puts), `puts`:

> Writes the given objects to ios as with IO#print. Writes a record
>   separator (typically a newline) after any that do not already end with
>   a newline sequence. **If called with an array argument, writes each
>   element on a new line.** If called without arguments, outputs a single
>   record separator.

---

BTW, I would code like this (using [`Enumerable#map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-map) + returning result instead of printing inside the function):

```
def skip_animals(animals, skip)
  animals.drop(skip).each_with_index.map { |animal, index|
    ("#{index + skip}:#{animal}")
  }
end

p skip_animals(['leopard', 'bear', 'fox', 'wolf'], 2)
```

Comment: This did get an array printing, but something in the code is still wrong.  Question edited above, any ideas?

Comment: @VirgeAssault, `"#{animal}:#{index}"`, `index` and `animal` should be swapped. Aren't they?, Check the last code in the answer.

Comment: yes, but the error is bc I'm getting two lines of output for some reason.  Can you check the edited code w/ output and see if you know why

Comment: @VirgeAssault, I cannot reproduce the symptom you have. Is there any other call except `skip_animals(['leopard', 'bear', 'fox', 'wolf'], 2)`?

Answer (score 0):

just remove `puts` remove form this line `puts arr.drop(skip)`

```
def skip_animals(animals, skip)
    arr = Array.new
    animals.each_with_index{|animal, index| arr.push("#{animal}:#{index}") }
    arr.drop(skip)
end
```

Comment: Without the `puts` nothing is put out.  I think I need to use p instead, but not sure about the STDIN stuff from HackerRank? Any ideas?